# Has been/was— which tense to use here?

Tags: tense

As it turns out your assuptions were true, as **has been** evidenced by her conviction for murder last week.

Here using **has been** is wrong and we should be using **was**, right? Since when we mention a time in the past, we go for the simple past and not the present perfect.

Comment: You are simply mistaken. Using ***has been*** in the cited context is perfectly okay (as is ***was***). Anyone who tries to tell you otherwise isn't a native speaker of English. Note that in the ***exact*** cited context, most native speakers probably wouldn't include any auxiliary verbs at all. And they'd probably go for a more common *main* verb: *...as **shown / demonstrated** by her conviction last week*.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence:

1. As it turns out your assuptions were true, as **has been evidenced** by her conviction for murder last week.

is correct. Alternatively, "was" can also be used:

2. As it turns out your assuptions were true, as **was evidenced** by her conviction for murder last week.

Or, still better, we could use a reduced participial clause:

3. As it turns out your assuptions were true, as **evidenced** by her conviction for murder last week.

The reason why the present perfect is possible despite the presence of the adverbial "last week" is that this adverbial may be considered as modifying "her conviction for murder":

4. As it turns out your assuptions were true, as **has been evidenced** by the fact that she **was convicted** for murder **last week**.

**What happened last week was that she was convicted for murder**. The realization or the recognition that the interlocutor's assumptions were true is not time-dependent and may be more recent, and this renders the present perfect perfectly possible.